# HTTP ERROR 500 on installed an existing laravel project

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan

I have installed an existing laravel project but when I run "php artisan serve" command it gives me below error.

> PHP Warning:  Unknown: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
>   [Thu Jul 20 12:07:12 2017] PHP Fatal error:  Unknown: Failed opening required '/Users/logicparadisemac/Sites/physicalproduct/server.php' (include_path='.:') in Unknown on line 0

Comment: Check that server.php exists in project directory. If not, copy it from clean Laravel install or find out why it was deleted from yours.

Comment: there is  index.php file in root folder instead

Comment: Thanks i copied server.php from fresh project and it worked.

Comment: Thanks a lot for help.